# How to display data from another model with some condition?

Tags: laravel

I have PostAd model and PostImage model.
They have one to many relationship.
One PostAd has many PostImage.

Now i want to display image of PostAd from PostImage with conditions where mainimage == 1.

```
PostAd model
public function postimage()
{
   return $this->hasMany(PostImage::class,'postad_id');
}
```

```
Controller of PostAd
 $data['userads']  =  PostAd::with('postimage')->where('user_id',$id)->paginate(4);
```

```
i want to display in blade file
 <td class="invert-image"><img src="{{asset('advertisementimage/'.$user->postimage->image)}}" alt="Images" class="img-responsive" style="width:50px;" /></td>
```

I want to display by applying condition in another model.
But shows me an error.  Property image doesn't exist on this collection instance.

Comment: can you show your PostImage model here?

Answer (score 0):

user this in your controller so you can get the post who has images

```
$data['userads']  =  PostAd::whereHas('postimage')->where('user_id',$id)->paginate(4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of your relationship is actually returning multiple PostImage. So you have to loop through the **$user->postimage** to access the **image** property.

Comment: yes it has multiple image. But how can i display only one image with conditions?

Comment: @A4family you can use **$user->postimage()->first()->image** to get the first image

Answer (score 0):

```
$data['userads']  =  PostAd::with(['postimage' => function ($query){
$query->whereNotNull('image');
}])->where('user_id',$id)->paginate(4);
```

You can apply your condition to the relation this way.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer.
I just applied the condition in Model.

```
public function postimage()
{
   return $this->hasMany(PostImage::class,'postad_id')->where('mainimage',1);
}
```